# Use `dir()` to just retrieve the `__all__` list from `__init__.py`

Tags: python-3.x, package

Once I load a package using the format below, is there a way to use `dir()` for just listing the values in the `__init__.py`'s `__all__` list without using a list comprehension regular expression?

```
from featurestore import featurestore as fs
```

I know its a simple question, just having a tough time finding an answer.

Comment: Just import it?! `from featurestore import __all__`

Answer (score 0):

Using suggestion by @SvenEberth, the following worked for me:

```
from featurestore import __all__ as fs_listing
print(fs_listing)
```